# Page contents being displayed differently in (any) browser and curl

Tags: networking, curl, web-scraping

Try:

```
curl http://meteo.search.ch/adsnow
```

and also visit this webpage using your browser. Notice that the contents are different (in the browser every link ends with snow-region but not in curl).

Now try to use the same headers as your browser. Still, you get different results. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm "The same headers" part: received "snow-region" when tested with the same headers as my browser.

I narrowed down the difference to `Accept-Language`, with this command is giving the same content as the browser:

```
curl -H 'Accept-Language: ru,ru-RU;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-us;q=0.2' http://meteo.search.ch/adsnow
```

Comment: It needs the header `Accept-Language`. Even `Accept-Language: en;" is enough.